# How to restrict IAM user for S3 Object maximum upload size 1 MB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to **restrict my IAM user for upload object size to only 1 MB**.
I have done a lot of research but couldn't found anything to restrict 
IAM user through policy Rules.

By default **AWS have S3 object restriction** 5TB, But I want to update this 
to 1 MB.

Please, suggest something who have any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to test this

```
{ "expiration": "'.date('Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z', time()+10).'",  
   "conditions": [  
        {"acl": "public-read" },
        {"bucket": "XXXXX" },   
        ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576] 
    ] 
}
```

*content-length-range - The minimum and maximum allowable size for the uploaded content.
                       ["content-length-range", 1048579, 10485760]*

Comment: Thanks Anil, The policy you shared is for POST policy . I want to restrict IAM user to s3 upload from console upload.I think you got my point.